# Prestashop v1.7 - Display a product details with few other product

Tags: prestashop-1.7

In prestashop version 1.7, each product details page should show few other products that other customer usually buy with that product. Is this possible? If so, kindly provide the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You go to the PrestaShop module pages, then in the selection tab, then you type in search "Cross-selling". The module is free.

Regards,